# How to send Client to Client SignalR messages

Tags: signalr

How to create to clients and initially 'handshake' via a SignalR hub and then communicate directly browser to browser? I remember a similar solution on this in the previous version @damianedwards mentioned a few years back in a (ch9?) podcast but can't find it.

Comment: @davidfowler suggested https://webrtc.org/

Comment: Be careful, it's little trick to get webrtc communicate over the internet. For browsers in the same network it's trivial to setup. Also your code should be prepared to fall back to client-server-client mode if webrtc isn't supported in any browser.